# What's the difference between IRBuilderBase and BinaryOperator in LLVM API?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

What's the difference between `IRBuilderBase` and `BinaryOperator` in LLVM API ?

Comment: IRBuilder is a builder class; it contains helper methods to build IR Instrructions. BinaryOperator is an Instruction subclass that models and, or, plus and the other operators that take two arguments and an opcode. Wasn't that clear from the names?

Comment: @arnt, If I want to create binary operation, is BinaryOperator the best practice ?

Comment: Opinions differ. Take a look at the IRBuilder/IRBuilderBase source if you want, it's not complicated. Just a bunch of two- and five-line methods.